# How to expand column height automatically and vertically align its contents?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to expand the height of first three col-md-1 divs to the rows maximum height which is expanded by two col-md-5, and also vertically align its contents. I am using grid system from bootstrap.

```
<div class="row load-container">
  <div class="col-md-1">{{Id}}</div>
  <div class="col-md-1"><img src="images/{{statusIcon Status}}" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"><div class="info-bubble info-bubble-small middle-align {{statusClass}}">{{Class}}</div></div>
  <div class="col-md-5 container">
    <div class="row">{{From.Name}}</div>
    <div class="row">{{From.City}} {{From.State}}, {{From.Zip}}</div>
    <div class="row">{{pickupFormatted}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 container">
    <div class="row">{{To.Name}}</div>
    <div class="row">{{To.City}} {{To.State}}, {{To.Zip}}</div>
    <div class="row">{{deliveryFormatted}}</div>
    <div class="row">{{expectedFormatted}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    {{Weight}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    {{Distance.text}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    {{Duration.text}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Here is the screen-cap to give an idea of the issue. Height of the first three columns is not extended to row's maximum height which is expanded by 4th and 5th columns. As a result, conent of those columns can't be vertically aligned in the middle.]

Edit:
Here is the method the sort-of works, except that the column widths are no longer affecting actual width.

```
.load-container {
    padding: 5px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}


.load-container [class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Ninja-edit:
This seems to work now

```
.load-container [class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `table` for that purposes

Comment: @antyrat That is what I tried at first, but it doesn't serve well for other purposes. I could use `table`, but then instead of working around couple visual issues I would be dealing with a dozen.

Comment: read this article http://chikuyonok.ru/2009/06/float-columns/. There is an example how to do what you want without using of table.